# Why my collection is empty when I send it?

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-5

I'm working with Laravel 5 and I've the following method in my Controller:

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $authUser =  Auth::user();
    $sharesList = Group::find($id)->shares->sortByDesc('created_at');
    $groupList = $authUser->groupsAsMember->where('id', '<>', $id);
    $group = $authUser->groups->find($id);
    $postList = Group::find($id)->posted->sortByDesc('created_at');

    $postsGroups = PostGroup::where('group_id', $id)->with('commented')->get();
    //$commentsList;

    foreach ($postsGroups as $postGroup) {
        $commentsList = $postGroup->commented;
        //dd($commentsList);
    }

    //dd($commentsList);
    return view('Pages.Group.detail', ['sharesList' => $sharesList, 'groupList' => $groupList, 'theGroup' => $group, 'postList' => $postList, 'commentsList' => $commentsList]);
}
```

The problem is of the `$commentsList` collection, if I put a `dd($commentsList)` inside the @foreach, I can see there's the elements that I want inside it, but if I put the `dd($commentsList)` outside the foreach (after @endforeach) $commentsList is empty and it arrives empty to my HTML page, how can I solve?
I tried to put `$commentsList;` before the @foreach loop but still not working.

**EDIT**

- How I want to get my data: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZs1I.jpg
- What I get(and I don't want): https://i.stack.imgur.com/6pMqD.jpg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overwriting it with each loop while you should add a new array element. Try this :

```
/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    $authUser =  Auth::user();
    $sharesList = Group::find($id)->shares->sortByDesc('created_at');
    $groupList = $authUser->groupsAsMember->where('id', '<>', $id);
    $group = $authUser->groups->find($id);
    $postList = Group::find($id)->posted->sortByDesc('created_at');
    $commentsList = collect();

    $postsGroups = PostGroup::where('group_id', $id)->with('commented')->get();

    foreach ($postsGroups as $postGroup) {
        foreach($postGroup->commented as $commentPost) {
            $commentsList->push($commentPost);
        }
    }

    //dd($commentsList);
    return view('Pages.Group.detail', ['sharesList' => $sharesList, 'groupList' => $groupList, 'theGroup' => $group, 'postList' => $postList, 'commentsList' => $commentsList]);
}
```

Comment: Just to say your missing a $ in the declaration of the array.

Comment: @Aurelien I tried your solution and I did a `dd($commentsList);` to see, but it returns to me an array of collections and It's not what I want, I need the Collection directly. Moreover, in this case it returns to me and extra collection empty, and it's wrong.

Comment: To be more precise, I need a collection of arrays, not an array of collections.

Comment: Well you can declare $commentsList as ArrayCollection and do adds instead of [], then use ArrayCollection's toArray() method to transform to array each sub element

Comment: I'm not very familiar with laravel syntax, but I did some research and edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: I get `local.ERROR: Method add does not exist.`

Comment: I'm sorry, it appears to be push instead of add. I updated the answer.

Comment: Don't worry, I fixed it... but anyway it doesn't give me the data how I want... I will edit my answer by post some images

Comment: As you can see in the images I've posted, with your solution I get a collection, of arrays, of collection, of arrays, of Model elements, and that's not what I want. I simply want a Collection, of arrays, of Model elements, as in the first image, I want all the results in one array.

Comment: I see better what you need now. I updated my answer. Your comment "I need a collection of arrays" was misleading, since what you wanted was a collection of object, actually.

Answer (score 1):

As you mention in comments you need collection of arrays so first initialize comment list:

```
$commentsList = [];
```

And then:

```
foreach ($postsGroups as $postGroup) {
    $commentsList[] = $postGroup->commented;
}
```